# How do I structure my Xamarin app to ensure crossplatform functionality?

Tags: xamarin

Hey I'm a Xamarin beginner who is a bit confused on how to structure my app to ensure cross-platform functionality while writing the smallest amount of code necessary. I have a library written in C and when using this library previously I would go the NDK route(for android), I now have to use the library for my Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.ios app. I want to know what the best way of achieving this goal is. Do I create a shared library or a PCL? Do I find a way to compile the library into a dll and just include in the Xamarin project?

Comment: You won't be able to your use C library with Android and iOS. You can probably compile with NDK and then use an API Binding project to link that into your Android app. Basically the only code that can be reused and shared across platforms is what you put in the PCL. That's usually your Xamarin Forms views, models and ViewModels. MVVM. Google Xamarin Forms MVVM Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking to C "native" libraries does not really change because you are using Xamarin, you still need to build all the various ARCH types, create universal/fat libs, etc...

On iOS you would be linking to a static lib or loading a .`dylib`:

[iOS Linking/Interop Native Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/)

On Android you would be using your `.so` just like NDK (`Xamarin.Android` produces an NDK-based app):

[Using Native Libraries on Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/)

*Note: If you are using Visual Studio, you also can debug your 'native' C/C++ along side your `Xamarin.Android` C# project.

In your C# code, in order to access methods defined in either one of those, you use Mono's P/Invoke functionality which is the same technology that you would use in .NET to access functions in C-based libraries.

[Accessing C Methods from C#](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#Accessing_C_Methods_from_C)